# Transform a pandas dataframe by concatenating columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

| Category | score_1 | score_2 | score_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.23 | 0.14 | 0.19 |
| B | 0.50 | 0.55 | 0.60 |
| C | 0.21 | 0.34 | 0.30 |

I would like to transform the previous DataFrame into the following one:

| Scores | Category | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| score_1 | A | 0.23 |
| score_1 | B | 0.14 |
| score_1 | C | 0.19 |
| score_2 | A | 0.50 |
| score_2 | B | 0.55 |
| score_2 | C | 0.60 |
| score_3 | A | 0.21 |
| score_3 | B | 0.34 |
| score_3 | C | 0.30 |

Is there any method in pandas to perform this kind of operation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.melt()`:

```
res = df.melt(id_vars='Category')

print(res)

  Category variable  value
0        A  score_1   0.23
1        B  score_1   0.50
2        C  score_1   0.21
3        A  score_2   0.14
4        B  score_2   0.55
5        C  score_2   0.34
6        A  score_3   0.19
7        B  score_3   0.60
8        C  score_3   0.30
```